# IIS7 - Question about blocking all IP addresses from accesing my site

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

If I want to allow ONLY two IP addresses and block ever other IP address from accessing my website, then is using "IP Address and Domian Restrictions" module in II7 a fool-proof way to do that? I have added two IP Addresses as "Allow Entry" and I have set "Access for unspecified clients" as "Deny". Now can I be sure that my website is safe? Also what's this "Enable domain name restrictions" checkbox under feature settings. Do I need to check mark that too? What does it do anyway?

**[edit]**
I am running my asp.net website on localhost. My internal network IP address is something like 192.168.x.x and the static IP address is diff and is same for all client PCs in my office. Now, I added this internal network IP address and the static IP address in IP Address and Domian Restrictions" module in II7 as "Allow Entry" and I set "Access for unspecified clients" as "Deny".

Now I am unable to run my website on local!! It says :-

> "HTTP Error 403.6 - Forbidden The IP address from which you are
>   browsing is not permitted to access the requested Web site."

Whats wrong?? How do you block IP addresses in IIS7 ? Please  help me..need it bad :( 
Whats going on here?

**IIS is obviously considering my PC's IP as one of the "UnSpecified clients" whose entry is denied. But when I HAVE added my network's static IP address AND my private network address in Allow Entry then why is it not letting me access the website??**

Comment: This might help http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730889(WS.10).aspx

Answer (score 1):

http://forums.iis.net/t/1153158.aspx

One easy way is to use IP Restrictions:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730889.aspx
Make sure to mark the "Access for unspecified clients" to Deny in the "Edit Feature Settings..." dialog

Comment: At least paste some content from the linked article!

Answer (score 0):

I use the following method to setup the  IP Restrictions.

http://linuxwebservertips.in/restrict-access-to-website-using-ip-address-in-iis-7/